# How to create a regular expression for last three weeks

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm using a custom dimension in Google Analytics which is date based. I need to create a regular expression to filter only data from the previous three weeks, but I don't understand how or if this can be done. The three weeks need to be always the most current three weeks, not three weeks from a hard coded date.

Here is a screenshot of the interface in GA. The dropdown that says, "containing" also includes an option for "regular expression." I need to be able to filter and show only the posts which were published during the past three weeks.

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s502/sh/3bf0574f-7309-47a9-9d8b-aff666e50605/513193900a7614584da12e26985a4635

Comment: You're probably going to need to expound on this.  Code snippets are always a plus.

Comment: Thank you @dustmouse. I don't have any code snippets. Here is a screenshot of the filter interface in Google Analytics.
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s502/sh/3bf0574f-7309-47a9-9d8b-aff666e50605/513193900a7614584da12e26985a4635

The dropdown that says "containing" also has "regular expression" as an option. I need to be able to say that I only want to show articles published within the last three weeks.

Comment: Okay, not a bad idea to include that in your post.

Comment: @dustmouse Thanks for the feedback. I edited the original question.

Comment: Looks like you are working on a dashboard widget. I don't think you can fix the date window to the "last three weeks". Have you tried just changing the date range in the upper right corner? Not what you want, but probably quickest.

Comment: It might be possible to hand-craft this each time you need it, but there is no feature in regex which can automatically check for dates, so you'd have to hand-craft a new regular expression every day. If you're determined to attempt this then you'll have to edit your question and show examples of your web page paths/names to show how the publishing date appears within them.

Comment: @Bobulous Thank you. I can close this then. I didn't know if it was even possible to do what I need to do. Since it's not, then I can simply use the date calendar to choose the previous three weeks.